# Ubuntu (or any gnome based distro) extremely laggy and slow only and only when installed in a VM

Tags: gnome, graphics, vmware, performance

When I install Ubuntu (latest LTS) in a virtual machine (regardless of the hypervisor, i.e. VMWare, Hyper-V, or VirtualBox), the graphics performance becomes annoyingly slow. For example, anytime I wanna open the application menu I can see footprints and trails of icons dragging themselves when entering the window and the same applies for almost anything else.

In case of VMWare Workstation Pro, I have properly installed VM Tools and enabled 3D Graphics Acceleration with 3Gb of Ram allocated for graphics performance only. The VM itself has been given 4 cores of CPU with about 6Gb of Ram which is more than enough for an Ubuntu Desktop. However, it is still terribly slow. Interestingly, CentOS with GUI which uses gnome as well suffers from a similar problem. Although this problem may not be directly linked to Ubuntu, I asked about that here because some Ask Ubuntu users might have run into the same issue and found a solution for that.

> Update:
>
> I tried it in different computers and I got the same result! laggy and
> slow!
>
> Another Update:
>
> Among all virtualization technologies I used VMWare showed the
> best performance which was still extremely laggy and slow, VirtualBox was
> a little worse than VMWare and Hyper-V was the most terrible.
>
> HTOP showed that nearly 70% of RAM was free and there was very little load on CPU.
>
> When I physically boot up with Ubuntu, it is very very fast!

Comment: Does your host pc have adequate specs? I use vb vms all the time and they work great. My host pc is no beast either.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: HP G-10 Web Server

Comment: The performance is so bad that it cannot even play Youtube videos properly! and the same things goes on in like 10 different computers.